# timepickerdialog minute input error

Tags: android, datetime, android-studio

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        if(hourOfDay < 10){
            strHourOfDay = "0" + hourOfDay;
        } else { strHourOfDay = String.valueOf(hourOfDay);}

        if(minute < 10){
            strMinute = "0" + minute;
        } else { strMinute = String.valueOf(minute);}

        period.put("hour",strHourOfDay);
        period.put("minute",strMinute);

        periodTime.setText(strHourOfDay + ":" + strMinute);
    }
};
```

I using TimePickerDialog for save hour and minute. 
hourOfDay input in strHourOfDay successfully. but minute failed to input in strMinute..

debugging result is under picture

[image]

what's the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Always use;

```
String.valueOf(minute);
```

if you want to parse a number (float, double, int, long) to `String`.

So your code should look like:

```
if(minute < 10) {
        strMinute = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
} else { 
      strMinute = String.valueOf(minute);
}
```